# NestJs - test on response from interceptor

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, interceptor

I have a simple interceptor that deletes a field from response:

```
import {
    CallHandler,
    ExecutionContext,
    Injectable,
    NestInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Response<T> {
    data: T;
}

@Injectable()
export class Transform<T> implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
    intercept(
        context: ExecutionContext,
        next: CallHandler,
    ): Observable<Response<T>> {
        return next.handle().pipe(
            map((response) => {
                delete response?.value?.name;
                return response;
            }),
        );
    }
}
```

How can I write test case for this? Basically, **I wanted to test if 'name' is deleted from response**. I wrote the following test case but response is coming as undefined:

```
  it('should delete `name` from response if present', async () => {
    transformInterceptor = new TransformRepoResponse();
    const context = {
      switchToHttp: () => ({
        getRequest: () => jest.fn(),
      }),
    };
    const next = {
      handle: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        pipe: jest.fn(),
      }),
    };
    requestMock.method = 'GET';
    const response = await transformInterceptor.intercept(context, next);
    expect(response.value.name).toBe(undefined);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Interceptors aren't `async` so you can't `await` their response without using `lastValueFrom()` as a wrapper. Also, your `next.handle()` should return an observable that will be acted on by the `.pipe`. Something like

```js
it('should delete `name` from response if present', (done) => {
    transformInterceptor = new TransformRepoResponse();
    const context = {
      switchToHttp: () => ({
        getRequest: () => jest.fn(),
      }),
    };
    const next = {
      handle: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of({
        value: {
          name: 'name-field',
          foo: 'foo-field',
        }
      }),
    };
    requestMock.method = 'GET';
    let errors = []
    transformInterceptor.intercept(context, next).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        try {
          expect(data).toEqual({
            value: { foo: 'foo-field' }
          })
        } catch (err) {
          errors.push(err);
        }
      complete: () => done(errors.length ? errors.join(' ') : undefined)
      }
    })
  });
```

Now you're testing the interceptor as an observable, you only expect one value so using the `next` of `subscribe` is fine, and you're telling Jest that the test is finished when the observable completes. You're also persisting any errors that happen by catching them in the `next` and using them as part of the `done` call if they exist.

Comment: thanks for your answer. One more question on this, my test case does not cover the branch in the line "delete response?.value?.name;". I wrote two test cases one with no "response", and the other with response, but without "value". But still it says "branch" not covered. How do I write test case to cover all the branches in the line?

Comment: I found one issue with this solution - That the test case never fails even if:
"        
expect(data).toEqual({
          value: { foo: 'foo-field' }
        })
"  
fails. Jest marks this test case as passed. Is it because the "expect" statement is given inside "next()"??

Comment: It should report if there's a problem. You can add in `error: reject` to that object and see if that fixes it

Comment: Where do I add "error: reject" ? Could you please update your answer?

Comment: Sorry, was thinking about promises with observables. It'd actually be `error: done` or explicitly `error: (err) => done(err)`

Comment: @TonyMathew I was incorrect in the use of `error`, I've updated the example to one that Jest _will_ report on if there is a failed error. You can probably abstract this out to make it easier to re-use across tests

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for your example:

```
import { CallHandler } from '@nestjs/common';
import { lastValueFrom, of } from 'rxjs';
import { createMocks } from 'node-mocks-http';
import { ExecutionContextHost } from '@nestjs/core/helpers/execution-context-host';

describe('Transform Interceptor test', () => {
  let transformInterceptor: Transform<any>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    transformInterceptor = new Transform();
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(transformInterceptor).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should remove the name', async () => {
    const { req, res } = createMocks();
    const testContext = new ExecutionContextHost([req, res]);
    const nextSpy: CallHandler<any> = {
      handle: () =>
        of({ what: 'ever', value: { name: 'Mario', something: 'else' } }),
    };

    await expect(
      lastValueFrom(transformInterceptor.intercept(testContext, nextSpy)),
    ).resolves.toEqual({ what: 'ever', value: { something: 'else' } });
  });
});
```

I found good hint for this solution here: https://github.com/leosuncin/nest-api-example/blob/master/src/auth/interceptors/token.interceptor.spec.ts